# How to eliminate expensive sub selects with joins

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone help me optimize this query.  It has expensive sub selects which have joins in them.

```
select distinct a.id1 
from xyz1 a, xyz2 b
where a.abc1 = 'ABC' 
and a.id1 = b.id1 
and b.abc2 = 10
and not exists(
  Select 1 
  from xyz3 c, xyz4 d
  where a.id1=c.id1
  and c.abc3 > 3
  and c.abc4 <> 7
  and c.id2 = d.id2
  and d.id3 in (1,11,111,2,22)
)
and not exists (
  Select 1 from xyz3 c ,xyz5 e
  where a.id1=c.id1
  and c.abc3 > 3
  and c.abc4 <> 7
  And c.id3=e.id4
  and e.id5 in (1,11,111,2,22)
);
```

I thought I could re write the query with the following but it returns different rows:

```
select distinct a.id1 
from xyz1 a, xyz2 b, xyz3 c,xyz4 d, xyz5 e
where a.abc1 = 'ABC' 
and a.id1 = b.id1 
and a.id1 = c.id1
and c.id3 = d.id2
and c.id3 = e.id4
and b.abc2 = 10
and not (
  c.abc3 > 3
  and c.abc4 <> 7
  and d.id3 in (1,11,111,2,22)
)
and not (
  c.abc3 > 3
  and c.abc4 <> 7
  and e.id5 in (1,11,111,2,22)
);
```

Also what I would like to know is it possible to pull out the sub select join add it to the main queries join and give the where condition as 'and not' and eliminate the 'not exists' sub select.

Comment: Kindly provide what is the result of first query and what is the result of second query.

Comment: It's because if i.e. one matching row in xyz5 exists, there will be now result row in the subselect version.. In the join-Version will be a result row for every non-matching row, merged into one through the distinct.

Comment: I won't help your performance, but you should use explicit `join` syntax. Old style implicit join syntax has been replaced in ANSI well over 30 years ago.

Comment: Sadly I cant because the data is secret.  I was hoping someone with high knowledge of SQL would be able to answer it easily and provide an optimized equivalent query.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that they are expensive with the explain plan, and also show what indexes are present? A NOT EXISTS correlated sub-query is most likely itself transformed to a anti-semijoin, and with appropriate indexes should not be a performance problem. Certainly the solution is not to automatically avoid NOT EXISTS.

Comment: providing an SQL fiddle might be a good idea, at least to check if our request works as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4

Answer (score 0):

This may be faster:

```
select a.id1 
from xyz1 a, xyz2 b
where a.abc1 = 'ABC' 
and a.id1 = b.id1 
and b.abc2 = 10
minus
select c.id1
from xyz3 c, xyz4 d
where c.abc3 > 3
and c.abc4 <> 7
and c.id2 = d.id2
and d.id3 in (1,11,111,2,22)
minus
select c.id1
from xyz3 c, xyz5 e
where c.abc3 > 3
and c.abc4 <> 7
And c.id3=e.id4
and e.id5 in (1,11,111,2,22)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### First : Let's rewrite the request in a non-deprecated way

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.id1
FROM
  xyz1 a
  INNER JOIN xyz2 b ON a.id1 = b.id1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c.id1 AS cid1
    FROM xyz3 c
      INNER JOIN xyz4 d ON c.id2 = d.id2
    WHERE c.abc3 > 3 AND c.abc4 <> 7 AND d.id3 IN (1,11,111,2,22)
  ) x ON a.id1 = x.cid1 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c.id1 AS cid1
    FROM xyz3 c
      INNER JOIN xyz5 e ON c.id3 = e.id4
    WHERE c.abc3 > 3 AND c.abc4 <> 7 AND e.id5 IN (1,11,111,2,22)
  ) y ON a.id1 = y.cid1
WHERE
  x.cid1 IS NULL AND y.cid1 IS NULL AND
  a.abc1 = 'ABC' AND b.abc2 = 10;
```

Here, we are getting ride of the old deprecated syntax. It shoudn't improve performance, Oracle is most likely translating your request to something closely related to this one during request processing.

#### Second: Try to optimize

```
WITH excluder AS (
  SELECT
    c.id1 AS cid1
  FROM xyz3 c
    LEFT JOIN xyz4 d ON c.id2 = d.id2 AND c.abc3 > 3 AND c.abc4 <> 7 AND d.id3 IN (1,11,111,2,22)
    LEFT JOIN xyz5 e ON c.id3 = e.id4 AND c.abc3 > 3 AND c.abc4 <> 7 AND e.id5 IN (1,11,111,2,22)
  WHERE
    d.id2 IS NULL OR e.id4 IS NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.id1
FROM
  xyz1 a
  INNER JOIN excluder z ON a.id1 = z.cid1
  INNER JOIN xyz2 b ON a.id1 = b.id1
WHERE a.abc1 = 'ABC' AND b.abc2 = 10;
```

1. We link both `d` and `e` to `c` (not not all the line, just the one that match the where clauses), in a way that it excluse all unwanted results. Let's name this new result-set `z`.
2. Then Link `z` to `a` to keep only non-excluded results.

I'm not a 100% sure that it produce the right output since i can't test it by myself, but it normally should. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Before you completely rewrite the query, try the effect of changing the subquery type first:

```
select distinct a.id1 
from xyz1 a, xyz2 b
where a.abc1 = 'ABC' 
and a.id1 = b.id1 
and b.abc2 = 10
and a.id1 not in (
  Select c.id1 
  from xyz3 c, xyz4 d
  where c.abc3 > 3
  and c.abc4 <> 7
  and c.id2 = d.id2
  and d.id3 in (1,11,111,2,22)
)
and a.id1 not in (
  Select c.id1 from xyz3 c ,xyz5 e
  where c.abc3 > 3
  and c.abc4 <> 7
  And c.id3=e.id4
  and e.id5 in (1,11,111,2,22)
);
```

Now you could also try combining the two subqueries into one:

```
select distinct a.id1 
from xyz1 a, xyz2 b
where a.abc1 = 'ABC' 
and a.id1 = b.id1 
and b.abc2 = 10
and a.id1 not in (
  Select c.id1 
  from xyz3 c, xyz4 d
  where c.abc3 > 3
  and c.abc4 <> 7
  and c.id2 = d.id2
  and d.id3 in (1,11,111,2,22)
  union
  Select c.id1 from xyz3 c ,xyz5 e
  where c.abc3 > 3
  and c.abc4 <> 7
  And c.id3=e.id4
  and e.id5 in (1,11,111,2,22)
);
```

This might be faster, or slower, only your tests can show.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you will "read" the xyz3 table once,
 and because of GROUP BYs the CBO will use HASH instead of SORT for the distinct values, which is faster than DISTINCT

```
WITH xyz3_t as (SELECT /*+ materialize */ 
                       c.id1
                  FROM xyz3 c
                 WHERE 1 = 1
                   AND c.abc3 > 3
                   AND c.abc4 <> 7
                 GROUP BY c.id1   
                )

SELECT a.id1
    FROM xyz1 a
 INNER JOIN xyz2 b
    ON a.id1 = b.id1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT c.id1
                    FROM xyz3_t c
                        ,xyz4 d
                   WHERE 1 = 1
                     AND c.abc3 > 3
                     AND c.abc4 <> 7
                     AND c.id2 = d.id2
                     AND d.id3 IN (1, 11, 111, 2, 22)
                   GROUP BY c.id1   
                     )   c
    ON a.id1 = c.id1                  

   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT c.id1
                      FROM xyz3_t c
                          ,xyz5 e
                     WHERE 1 = 1
                       AND c.abc3 > 3
                       AND c.abc4 <> 7
                       AND c.id3 = e.id4
                       AND e.id5 IN (1, 11, 111, 2, 22)
                    )  e 
    ON a.id1 = e.id1                                                             

 WHERE a.abc1 = 'ABC'    
     AND b.abc2 = 10
     AND c.id1 IS NULL
     AND e.id1 IS NULL
GROUP BY a.id1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your data, you're asking us to guess.  So, here's my guess.  It's not necessarily better than the others (e.g., I like @Martin Schapendonk's) `MINUS` approach.

Anyway, this approach does a few things:

1) Replaces the `JOIN` to `xyz2` with an `EXISTS` and get's rid of the `DISTINCT`.  I'm assuming `a.id1` is unique and that the `DISTINCT` was only introduced to get rid of duplicates introduced by the join to `xyz2`.  By using an `EXISTS`, you won't be doing the `NOT EXISTS` subquery later on on a bunch of duplicate rows.

2) Combines the two `NOT EXISTS` subqueries into one.

```
SELECT a.id1
FROM   xyz1 a
WHERE  a.abc1 = 'ABC'
AND    EXISTS
         (SELECT 'b record'
          FROM   xyz2 b
          WHERE  b.id1 = a.id1
          AND    b.abc2 = 10)
AND    NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT 1
          FROM   xyz3 c
          WHERE  a.id1 = c.id1
          AND    c.abc3 > 3
          AND    c.abc4 <> 7
          AND    (EXISTS
                    (SELECT 'd record'
                     FROM   xyz4 d
                     WHERE  d.id2 = c.id2
                     AND    d.id3 IN (1,11,111,2,22))
          OR      EXISTS
                    (SELECT 'e record'
                     FROM   xyz5 e
                     WHERE  e.id4 = c.id3
                     AND    e.id5 IN (1,11,111,2,22))))
```